# Xcode error when build project in flutter

Tags: xcode, flutter, macos, flutter-dependencies, xcode12.3

[image]I am new in flutter.I uses Xcode version-12.3 and flutter version Flutter 2.10.4.
when I build the project in Xcode I got an error Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code.
And when i try to build in terminal an error- Encountered error while building for device.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jbnQ.png)

When I run the project in terminal it gives a warning:Your Flutter application is created using an older version of the Android
embedding. It is being deprecated in favor of Android embedding v2

will it make any difference to build my project.

Comment: You need to resolve error prom you project first lib/util/Apptheme.dart file has some errors you have to resolve it first

Comment: if you open your project with xcode and run it the error will be more explicit, often it is a signing issue or somethng similiar.

Comment: Sir I am using Xcode to run the project, there is no signing issue but I got an error to build a project. @flutterloop

Comment: sir after modify the Apptheme.dart file I got an error. I updated in description image2.@HardikMehta